# Cannot create unknown type clr-namespace;assembly in xaml usercontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've been searching Google and StackOverflow high and low and I can't seem to find a valid answer; I've got an IValueConverter in a class library I maintain and I'd like to pass it along to a (3rd party) component which creates file-prints out of XAML files.
The newly created ClassLibrary is (although sharing beginning of namespace) not part of the same project/solution (and can't be).

My questions
1) Can XAML load "external" class libraries on the fly?
2) I so, how do I reference this class library?

What I've did and tried so far;
I've added an IValueConverter class to my class library called UtcTimeConverter with a fairly simple convert date time to Utc time function.

I've compiled it both normally and compiled as resource.

I've tried with or without assembly=

XAML:

```
    <UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:components="clr-namespace:XX.YY.Printing;assembly=XX.YY.Printing"
    xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:XX.YY.Printing.DesignData;assembly=XX.YY.Printing"
    xmlns:mcl="clr-namespace:XX.YY.MyClassLib;assembly=XX.YY.MyClassLib"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance dd:SampleXXViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="50.86cm" Width="4.9cm"
    FontFamily="Arial"
    FontWeight="Bold"
    FontSize="0.3cm">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <mcl:UtcTimeConverter x:Key="utcTimeConverter" />

SNIP

<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding dateOfIssue, Converter={StaticResource utcTimeConverter}, StringFormat=\{0:ddMMMyy HH:mm\}}"  FontSize="12" />
```

My class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace XX.YY.MyClassLib
{
    public class UtcTimeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value is IConvertible)) return value;

            return System.Convert.ToDateTime(value).ToUniversalTime();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

The other XX.YY things are available, I can use these, but somehow my new class is never called; this is the error message:

> Cannot create unknown type
>   '{XX.YY.MyClassLib}UtcTimeConverter'.' Line number '17' and
>   line position '10'.:    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Uri baseUri)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   ParserContext parserContext)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(XmlReader reader, ParserContext
>   parserContext, XamlParseMode parseMode)    at
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(Stream stream, ParserContext
>   parserContext)    at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(Stream
>   stream)

Comment: Look how `xmlns:dd` is declared.

Comment: Yes- like I said, I tried with and without the assembly part (this was the final-straw-let's-try-without-assembly-version) but I'll adjust for readability sake,

Comment: How about the `clr-namespace:` prefix? Also make sure the assembly is referenced in your project.

Comment: The classLibrary is outside of the original project, this is an add-on and needs to be loaded run-time (if possible) - that is one of my questions; can it?

Comment: When you want to use it in XAML, it must be referenced.

Comment: That explains why it can't load. Thank you.